# How adjust direction of my arrow in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a `ggplot` chart where I want to have some arrows between two points. The main task is easily done with `geom_line(arrow = arrow())`, but as you can see the arrow don't signal the correct direction of "Previo" to "Actual" for some observations (Germany, France). This is my code:

```
Countries = c("Eurozone","Eurozone","France","France","Germany","Germany","Japan","Japan","United.Kingdom","United.Kingdom","United.States","United.States")
PMI = c(62.5,63.3,59.3,59.2,66.6,66.4,52.7,53.3,58.9,60.7,59.1,60.6)
Delta1M = c(4.6,0.8,3.2,-0.1,5.9,-0.2,1.3,0.6,3.8,1.8,0.5,1.5)
Mes = c("Previo","Actual","Previo","Actual","Previo","Actual","Previo","Actual","Previo","Actual","Previo","Actual")

t1 <- data.frame(Countries,PMI,Delta1M,Mes)
t1$Mes <- factor(t1$Mes, levels = c("Previo","Actual"))

t1 %>% arrange(Countries) %>% 
  group_by(Countries) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = PMI, y = Delta1M, group = Countries))+
  geom_point(aes(color = Countries, alpha = Mes), size = 3)+
  geom_line(arrow = arrow(length=unit(0.15,"cm"), ends="last", type = "closed"))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 50)+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.3,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting by Mes and using `geom_path` seems to work, by drawing the line in the order of the sorted data rather than based on x progression.

```
t1 %>% arrange(Countries, Mes) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = PMI, y = Delta1M, group = Countries))+
  geom_point(aes(color = Countries, alpha = Mes), size = 3)+
  geom_path(arrow = arrow(length=unit(0.15,"cm"), ends="last", type = "closed"))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 50)+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.3,1))
```

[image]